# Array filtering using NSPredicate in objective-c gives error

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate, array-filter

I have an array within objects like below;

```
NSMutableArray* tableStructure = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

TableStructure *structure = [[TableStructure alloc] init];
                    structure.TableName =@"Client";
                    structure.Type =@"U";
                    structure.ColumnName =@"Id";
                    structure.DataType =@"int";
                    structure.Length = 2;

TableStructure *structure2 = [[TableStructure alloc] init];
                    structure2.TableName =@"Client";
                    structure2.Type =@"U";
                    structure2.ColumnName =@"Name";
                    structure2.DataType =@"text";
                    structure2.Length = 20;

[tableStructure addObject:structure];
[tableStructure addObject:structure2];


 NSString *typeFilter = @"U";
 NSString *nameFilter = @"sysname";
 NSString *tableNameFilter = @"Sync";

 NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Type == %@ and DataType != %@ and TableName != %@)", typeFilter, nameFilter, tableNameFilter];

 NSArray *filteredArray = [tableStructure filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

When the debugger came to NSPredicete *pred... line, it gives `'Unable to parse the format string "Type == %@ and DataType != %@ and TableName != %@)"'` error.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an unbalanced closing parenthesis in the predicate string:

```
@"Type == %@ and DataType != %@ and TableName != %@)"
                                           HERE ---^
```

If you remove that it should work.

Comment: I removed. Debugger passed that line but predicate produces no result at this time.

Comment: @MehmetInce: That is strange. I have tested exactly your code and the result was an array of two objects (because both objects match the predicate).

Answer (score 1):

You simply have an orphaned ")", try this: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Type == %@ and DataType != %@ and TableName != %@", typeFilter, nameFilter, tableNameFilter];`
`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,No need of `)`

```
 NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Type == %@ and DataType != %@ and TableName != %@", typeFilter, nameFilter, tableNameFilter];
```